flutter will not connect to the firebase
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.1.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.1.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.1.pom
Required by:
project :


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
how to solve this error in flutter in android studio

Can you share some more info on this?

You should change the version of ext.kotlin.version to 1.7.10. This code in the android/build.gradle file. It seems like this:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

...

}

